# 'boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.isDestroyed()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, fragment, androidx

I get this error crash

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.isDestroyed()' on a null object reference
```

When activity onStop() and when i remove fragment from FragmentTransaction

i added

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

to all my fragment, but it is not help

My code

```
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    //t.replace(R.id.calendar1, weekendCaldroidFragment);
                    t.detach(weekendCaldroidFragment).add(R.id.calendar1, weekendCaldroidFragment).attach(weekendCaldroidFragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: If you are calling methods with reflection in an Activity, you should not be suprised when you get null poitners from Framework lifecycle methods you did not call yourself.

Comment: What i need to do ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Remove all of that code from `onDetach()` - it is not necessary on any recent version of Fragments and is exactly what is causing the crash.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't deleted it from everywhere. The variable itself is non-null, so the only way it would be null is if you set it to null via reflection.

Comment: @ianhanniballake you save my life buddy +1

Comment: When I am using Caldroid Fragment and this Fragment destroyed then only this issue comes. My App is in Androidx compitable but CaldroidFragment Library is nou. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @YashBhardwaj thans for comments... I was trying solve the problem.... After that loking  official  page there are  comment that solve problem https://github.com/vpotvin/CaldroidX

Comment: Remove onDetach() from BaseFragment and its works Thanks